# How to auto-complete with comma-separated citations?

Tags: biblatex, texmaker, auto-completion, comma-separated-list

I am using TexMaker and I want my editor to auto-complete the `\parencite{}` command for biblatex for any number of arguments.

I already added `\parencite{#bib#}` in `User > customize Completion`, but I want auto-completion for comma-separated sources. By example:

```
\parencite{fooBar2020, BazBuzz2021}
\parencite{fooBar2020, BazBuzz2021, [more arguments]}
```

Is there a way to achieve that?

Comment: Does it work for other built-ins like `\cite`? If not, that would probably be something to contact the developers about.

Comment: @moewe Good point. It is not supported by cite. Probably not implemented at all? Do you know some editor which implements it?

Comment: You might want to try TeXstudio, whose auto-complete features are slightly more customisable than TeXmaker's. But I'm the wrong person to ask about editors, I usually use Notepad++ or TeXworks (and Emacs when I'm feeling bold).

Comment: TeXstudio's autocompletion supports comma-separated list in `\cite{...}`, and will auto work for `\parancite` if `biblatex` package is loaded. For any user defined commands, add `\parencite{keylist}#c` to a [`.cwl` file under specific path](https://github.com/texstudio-org/texstudio/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#what-are-cwl-files-good-for-and-how-do-they-work).

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ Do you want to type up a quick answer explaining that at least TeXstudio does the desired thing?

Comment: @moewe Just added an extended version of that comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(This is an extended version of [my previous comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/577809/how-to-auto-complete-with-comma-separated-arguments?noredirect=1#comment1454485_577809).)

I'm not familiar with TeXMaker, but TeXstudio does the desired thing. That is, in TeXstudio,

- auto-completion for comma-separated citations in `\cite{...}` is supported,
- if package `biblatex` is loaded, then that in `\parencite{...}` is also supported.

Moreover, suppose you have `\newcommand\mycite[2][]{\cite[#1]{#2}}`, then you can make TeXstudio's auto-completion support `\mycite` by adding

```tex
\mybib{bibid}#c
\mybib[post note]{bibid}#c
```

to a `.cwl` file under TeXstudio's config path and mark it autoloaded in Configure -> Completion.

Related TeXstudio docs:

- [What are cwl files good for and how do they work?](https://github.com/texstudio-org/texstudio/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#what-are-cwl-files-good-for-and-how-do-they-work) - wiki
- [4.14 Description of the cwl format](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/texstudio-org/texstudio/master/utilities/manual/usermanual_en.html#CWLDESCRIPTION) - user manual